# Create a document library or retrieve documents using JavaScript from static site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-on-prem

I'm confused by all integration options SharePoint offers. My business case is the following:

I have a static HTML/CSS/JavaScript site hosted outside of SharePoint (so cross domains is an issue here too). My JavaScript code knows the URL of my customers SharePoint site. From my JavaScript code I, for example, want to create a Document Library or retrieve documents from existing document libraries.

Which options do I have to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

use Javascript client object model to retrive data from sharepoint list.Sharepoint site should have Anonymous access.

Sample reference : [JSOM](http://sharepoint-tamizha.blogspot.in/2013/08/get-sharepoint-list-items-using.html)

Comment: This won't work since the page is not located in SharePoint. JSOM accesses the {sp}/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery endpoint for its requests.

Answer (score 0):

These are possible options:

### Use Rest

SharePoint provides most of it's actions as REST endpoints. This could possibly cause some problems regarding the Cross-Origin policies. 
You can't use request batching here so you may suffer a lack of performance.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx)

### [Preferred] Use .NET CSOM (serverside)

This will work as long as you can access the from your Server (open the Url in the browser to check). If you need your code callable from the frontend just create some WebMethods or something similar to access your serverside code.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will give REST a try, and if it works mark your answer as solution. CSOM is not an option, because I can't run server side code in my case.